# Store specific url in static block

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, url, store-view, static-block

I have a multistore website in Magento CE 1.9.2.4 in which stores are differentiated in url like:

```
http://mywebsite.com/store1 &
http://mywebsite.com/store2
```

Now how to get the above store-specific urls in static block by using the `{{store url="store1"}}` or `{{store url="store2"}}`

Right now the above syntax is not working and it fetches the default base url only and not the store-specific one.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use this syntax:

{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}

- instead of {{store url=""}}